# Hacking machines using internet packets

Tags: encryption, sniffer, iphone, packet

I have a friend (X) who hacked the whatsapp account of someone (Y) using iphone. He told me that he sent a packet to the iphone of Y that appears as a normal whatsapp message but now he can see all the chat of Y. My question is how did he do it exactly and what's the name of this technique? Don't iphone or other machines have any security against such attacks (maybe encryption)? Does this technique apply universally to any computer?

Comment: Either 'sent a packet' is a incredibly broad oversimplification, or he is just feeding you a line of crap.

Comment: Or, by "packet" he meant "email", in which case, it was a simple phishing attack.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the others that 'sent a packet' is an incredibly broad statement, but it's already been passed on 2nd hand from a script kiddie who may not even understand the exploit in the first place.

I assume he's probably exploiting a buffer overflow or other low-level bug in the communication layer.

Such exploits are specific to the particular app, not the OS or device, and they definitely don't apply to all devices.  In a perfect world, the app would use encryption, signatures, and data validation to help prevent buffer overflows, but it's not a perfect world.  So, the scenario as described is entirely possible and in fact happens all the time with different apps.

Answer (score -1):

I think both "hack with iPhone" and "sent a packet" are a piece of crap.

There are many ways to crack a username and password. First, hacker can use "brute force attack" to try every possible combination of password. Some even use a rainbow table, it is a table of common password, so it takes less time to crack a password.
Second, a hacker can inject a "key logging virus on your PC, so every keystrokes are recorded, thus collect the password.

(There are much more password cracking method)

Comment: Well, he mentioned [backtrack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BackTrack) and he said that sometimes he can't see the whatsapp conversation of Y until the auto-backup.

Comment: "Backtrack" is a Linux Distro use for pen-test(or hacking), it includes more than 200 tools for hacking, your friend is probably a beginner hacker and have no knowledge in computer or hacking

Comment: Just search "Kail Linux" or "pen-test" in google and you will get tons of information about pentest/hacking. You will get nothing if you search "hacking".